# Ada - (Streams) How to correctly call String'Read () without knowing string length beforehand

Tags: string, serialization, stream, ada

I'm attempting to write a quick program to send AT commands to a serial-port modem.  I have opened the port with the right settings (B115200, 8N1 etc) and the String'Write call in the below code sample does actually work correctly.

Now I'm adding the code to read the modem's response back as a string.  However I cannot know the length of the response beforehand and hence I cannot create a String variable to pass in to the `out String` parameter unless I *do* know the length.

```
  package GSC renames GNAT.Serial_Communications;

  SP : aliased GSC.Serial_Port;

  function Send (Port : in GSC.Serial_Port; S : in String) return String is
  begin
    String'Write (SP'Access, S);
    delay 0.1;

    declare
      Retval : String;  -- NOT VALID - needs to be initialised
    begin
      String'Read (SP'Access, Retval);
      return Retval;
    end;
  end Send;
```

I have a chicken / egg situation here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is probably to read the input one character at a time until you reach the terminator.

You could allocate a buffer long enough to hold the longest possible response (e.g. 1024 bytes!) (or maybe use recursion - but that’d be more complicated and make it difficult to diagnose possible overrun errors).

Comment: Oh, recursion those depth is not limited internally is a good idea to get stack overflow due to malfunctioning device.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is terminated by a specific character, you could use `Interfaces.C.Pointers`:

```
function Receive (Port : in GSC.Serial_Port) return String is
   package Character_Pointers is new Interfaces.C.Pointers (
     Index => Positive, Element => Character, Element_Array => String,
     Default_Terminator => Character'Val (13)); -- CR-Terminated
   function Convert is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (
     Source => access all Streams.Stream_Element,
     Target => Character_Pointers.Pointer);
   --  assuming no more than 1023 characters + terminator can be given.
   Max_Elements : constant Streams.Stream_Element_Offset :=
     1024 * Character'Size / Streams.Stream_Element'Size;
   Buffer : Streams.Stream_Element_Array (1 .. Max_Elements);
   Last : Stream_Element_Offset;
begin
   Port.Read (Buffer, Last);
   return Characters_Pointers.Value (Convert (Buffer (1)'Access));
end Receive;
```

This code makes several assumptions:

- String is terminated with CR (can be modified by setting `Default_Terminator` appropriately).
- The response contains nothing other than the string (additional content that may have been read after the string is silently discarded).
- The whole content will never be longer than 1024 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to achieve this is to send the length first, then read the value. (This is what things like `bencode` do.) -- Something like:

```
-- A stream from Standard-Input; for passing to example parameters:
Some_Stream: not null access Ada.Streams.Root_Stream_Type'Class :=
      Ada.Text_IO.Text_Streams.Stream( Ada.Text_IO.Standard_Input );

-- The simple way, use the 'Input attribute; this calls the appropriate
-- default deserializations to return an unconstrained type.
-- HOWEVER, if you're reading from an already extant data-stream, you may
-- need to customize the type's Input function.
Some_Value : Constant String := String'Input( Some_Stream );

-- If the stream places a length into the stream first, you can simply read
-- it and use that value, to prealocate the proper size and fill it with the
-- 'Read attribure.
Function Get_Value( Input : not null access Ada.Streams.Root_Stream_Type'Class ) return String is
    Length : Constant Natural := Natural'Input( Input );
Begin
    Return Result : String(1..Length) do
        String'Read( Input, Result );
    End Return;
End Get_Value;

-- The last method is to use when you're dealing with buffered information.
-- (Use this if you're dealing with idiocy like null-terminated strings.)
Function Get_Buffered_Value( Input : not null access Ada.Streams.Root_Stream_Type'Class;
                             Buffer_Size : Positive := 1024;
                             Full_Buffer : Boolean  := True;
                             Terminator  : Character:= ASCII.NUL
                            ) return String is
    Buffer : String(1..Buffer_Size);
Begin
    -- Full_Buffer means we can read the entire buffer-size w/o
    -- "overconsuming" -- IOW, the stream is padded to buffer-length.
    if full_buffer then
        String'Read(Input, Buffer);
        declare
            Index : Natural renames Ada.Strings.Fixed.Index(
               Source  => Buffer,
               Pattern => (1..1 => Terminator),
               From    => Buffer'First
              );
        begin
            Return Buffer(Buffer'First..Index);
        end;
    else
        declare
            Index : Positive := Buffer'First;
        begin
            -- Read characters.
            loop
                Character'Read( Input, Buffer(Index) );
                exit when Buffer(Index) = Terminator;
                Index:= Positive'Succ( Index );
                exit when Index not in Buffer'Range;
            end loop;

            -- We're returning everything but the terminator.
            Return Buffer(1..Positive'Pred(Index));
        end;
    end if;
End Get_Buffered_Value;
```